# Are there any M.Y. criteria or policies in deciding when someone should post an additional answer vs. editing the first answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, policy

See [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59409/why-do-we-refer-to-shavuot-as-the-time-of-receiving-the-torah-when-all-that-oc/59429#59429). One user has posted 2 answers. It seems that they are merely different sources for answering the question. I'm wondering if it would have made sense just to merge these 2 answers into 1.

Are there any guidelines or is there any policy regarding when to post an additional answer to a question?

Answer (score 8):

See [What is the official etiquette on answering a question twice?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25209/259693) on MSE. The top answer there states:

> When you have two distinct answers.
>
> It's better to post two different answers than to put them both into one answer.
>
> [snip]
>
> If you put two very different answers in one, then one could be a great answer, and one could be a terrible way to do things, but the upvotes (or downvotes) on the good (or bad) answer will drag the other along with it to the top (or bottom).

Personally, i think that in the case you gave, the answers are different enough to warrant being posted separately.